# EOS account's public in scatter

Tags: public-key, scatter

When use scatter, I can see scatter.identity.publicKey. However it is not  he EOS account's public key.(It looks like some public key generated by scatter).  How can I get the account's public key from  scatter.

Comment: When you say "use" do you mean the way a regular user would use it? If you open the Scatter extension in Chrome, normally you can click "Key Pairs" and the public key will be partially shown under each account. You can copy the full public key with the left icon (across from the red icon).

Comment: I mean how to access the public key  in javascript like eosjs

Answer (score 1):

You can use the key pairs section in your scatter extension:

[image: Key Pairs in scatter]